# Updating server behind a firewall

Tags: command-line-interface, windows, windows-update

I currently have 4 server that sit behind a firewall and do not have internet access. In fact they are locked down pretty tight. The 5th server on the network (the domain control) however, has outside/internet access. I need to apply updates to all 5 of these servers. I cannot for one second allow an internet connection to the other servers unfortunately. (Contract reasons). It is my understanding that I can run a command within each server that allows me to check for the most recent updates on that server and then download the required updates from the internet server. If that makes sense.

I have heard something about **MBSA** allowing this capability or something along that nature. Are there any other suggestions I may want to look into to get the servers updated behind a firewall with the most recent updates? Also what command line prompts would I look into using to make this project work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into WSUS ([Windows Server Update Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157)), free tool, that does exactly what you want.

It runs on one server with Internet access, and takes care of updating other servers behind the firewall.

> Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) enables information technology administrators to deploy the latest Microsoft product updates to computers that are running the Windows operating system. By using WSUS, administrators can fully manage the distribution of updates that are released through Microsoft Update to computers in their network.

Note that you should not run this on the domain controller, so if licensing allows it deploy a new machine for this purpose.

Comment: I marked this as correct only because I realized I made a mistake. I did not mention that I am dealing with ancient servers, Windows 2000. Therefore WSUS does not work. MBSA is what I will be using on these servers as it is more reliable across all server based operating systems.

Comment: All information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647642.aspx)

Comment: what windows 2000 patches are you getting still?

Comment: These servers have not been monitored and are out of date by about 5 years or so. They are in desperate need of attention.